# AddError on Before Update

Tags: apex, before-trigger, adderror

I am trying to display an error message if a field on Quote is updated to a certain value. I am doing it on before update but I am encountering an error
[image]
[image]

Here is a sample code block I am trying on my org

Comment: Querying the quotes from the database based on the ids of the triggered records is unnecessary. The `quotes` variable already contains everything you need.

Answer (score 4):

Been a while since I used it but the docs state `Trigger.New`...

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_exceptions.htm

> Triggers can be used to prevent DML operations from occurring by
> calling the addError() method on a record or field. When used on
> Trigger.new records in insert and update triggers, and on Trigger.old
> records in delete triggers, the custom error message is displayed in
> the application interface and logged.

Now I've just tested for myself, the following works:

```
trigger ContactTrigger on Contact (before insert, before update) {
    contactUtils.testAddError(trigger.new);
}

public class contactUtils {
    public static void testAddError(List<Contact> conList){
        for(Contact con : conList){
            con.addError('nope.');
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I realize I was able to make it work if I use that same format as yours. I am getting the issue when I try to query and reference a field from another Object related to Quote. Is that possible on before update? I updated the screenshot of my code

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the error to Trigger.new or Trigger.newMap, unless you're in a delete trigger, in which case you use Trigger.old or Trigger.oldMap.

Given your code, you can get the record from the Trigger.newMap variable:

```
// Or, ideally, pass in Trigger.newMap as well.
Map<Id, sObject> newQuotesById = new Map<Id, sObject>(quotes);
if(arv.contains(bc)) {
  newQuotesById.get(q.Id).addError('Error');
}
```