Can we override the System defined Exception message using the Custom Exception Handling?
I have tried to handle the system defined Exception using the Custom Exception in Apex but only the message part gets overriden. Is there any chance that we can override the entire system defined Exception message(like class name, line number, stack trace etc.) such that I can show only the custom error message to the users when they forgot to fill any field vaule(like how the validation message is shown).
Please find the below Exception Class that i was referencing for Custom Exception.
public class CustomException extends Exception {}

Please find the below class.
public class AccountTriggerHandler {  
    
try{                                                                                    
    for(Account acc: triggerNew){                                                          
        acc.num2__c = acc.num1__c+1;    }         
}     
catch(Exception e){                                                                            
    throw new CustomException('Num1 field is blank.'); } } }
                                                    

Note: My issue was in After Update but i am attaching the image of before update for explanation purpose.
Please find the below screenshot for the overriden message(marked in red color border).


this might help - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/346913/adderror-on-before-update

actually, my scenario was in after update. the above example is for just explanation purpose to show how the custom message is overriden with the system defined exception

Idea was to show the addError message that could be uses for that purpose to add "custom" error message

if it is in before event i can directly use the addError.
but, my scenario was in after update(where i cannot use the addError), so i tried to override the system defined exception message using the custom Exception class.
hope you got my point...

In any trigger context, avoid throwing exceptions, as the answers in the linked question state. Doing so cancels the entire transaction, when it might have otherwise partially succeeded (e.g. when using the Apex Data Loader). addError is always the correct way to go. And yes, addError even works in an after update trigger. Make sure you're adding the error to Trigger.new records.
